# Is every Dedekind domain the integral closure of some principal ideal domain?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I mean that $B$ is a Dedekind domain with fraction field $L$, which is a finite separable extension of a field $K$ that is the fraction field of a PID $A$ such that $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

If the question in the title is true, one can give a new proof of the unique factorization property of Dedekind domains like the proof for number rings given in Hecke's classical book "Lectures on the Theory of Algebraic Numbers."

**Edit**: R. van Dobben de Bruyn has given an ingenious counterexample in the comment below.

Comment: I made some edits to the title and to the body of the question.  Let me know if the edits accurately reflect what you wanted to ask.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, a counterexample can be constructed as follows: start with a quadratic ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ with nontrivial class group, take a principal prime ideal $\mathfrak p = (\alpha)$ that is not the only prime lying over $(p) = \mathfrak p \cap \mathbf Z$, and look at $\mathcal O_K[1/\alpha]$. It is not a PID itself, and the only PID below it is $\mathbf Z$, whose integral closure is $\mathcal O_K$ and not $\mathcal O_K[1/\alpha]$. Of course for your argument, it suffices that $B$ is a *localisation* of an integral closure of a PID.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks; this is precisely I wanted to ask.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Many thanks for your ingenious counterexample.

Comment: Essentially the same counterexample was given by [Claborn](https://msp.org/pjm/1965/15-1/p08.xhtml) in 1965, which as far as I know is the oldest counterexample to this conjecture. However these examples are still localizations of such integral closures of PIDs. I wonder if there are examples of Dedekind domains which are not of this form either.